# How to extract the first letter of each word and preserve the spacing, punctuation, capitalization, and line breaks of original text in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

If I put the following text in a cell:

```
I'm a little teapot, short and stout. 
Here is my handle, here is my spout. 
When I get all steamed up - hear me shout! 
Tip me over and pour me out.
```

I would like for the output in another cell to be:

```
I' a l t, s a s. 
H i m h, h i m s. 
W I g a s u - h m s!
T m o a p m o.
```

There will never be numbers in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex pattern seems to be working:

```regex
\b(\S)[^'\s]*('?)\S*\b
```

And then just replace with `$1$2`.  [See the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/QVQiFP/1).  Here is the Google Sheets code you may use:

```
REGEXREPLACE("your text here", "\b(\S)[^'\s]*('?)\S*\b", "$1$2")
```

Explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
\b       word boundary on the left
(\S)     match and capture the first letter of each word
[^'\s]*  then consume any non whitespace content which is also not apostrophe
('?)     match and capture an apostrophe, if present
\S*      consume the remainder of the word
\b       word boundary on the right
```